# ViewController view starts with at ~(0,20)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've tried starting view based app and window based app but I still have the same problem.
When I add a navigation bar it looks like it starts at cords ~(0,20) and leaves some space between the it and the "system tray" (i can't find the word for the dock with clock and batteri etc.)

i can't figure out why this occurs because the nslog of frame tells me that it origins in (0,0) (and strangely the width is 0 :/ but it is clearly visible).

code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 
                                                                       self.view.frame.origin.y+48.0f, 
                                                                       self.view.frame.size.width, 
                                                                       self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0792.PNG"]];
        [self.view addSubview:image];

        self.navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 
                                                                    self.view.frame.origin.y, 
                                                                    self.view.frame.size.width, 
                                                                    45.0f)];

        [navBar setDelegate:self];    
        [navBar pushNavigationItem: [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Image Stream"] animated:NO];
        [self.view addSubview:navBar];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and in the appdelegate i just declare it, retain-property and:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.menu = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.window setRootViewController:menu];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

would be very nice if someone knew why this happens. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When positioning a view using the coordinates of the superview, use bounds, not frame. If there's a status bar, your superview.frame.x will be non-zero, but the subview's coordinates are relative to the superview, not the position.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

- In your `UIViewController's` Xib if it has status bar. If yes, then put None. (You can set that in the inspector, just select your root `UIView`.
- Are you adding your `UIViewController` to your App delegate's by XIB? If yes, go check in the App's delegate xib your `UIViewController` and see if it has status bar.

p.s: its called status bar.

Edit what about the frame you use for your UINavigation? The 45.0f.

Comment: I don't have a XIB for the VC, and as you can see I don't initiate it with one: `[[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`
And appdelegate xib I guess you mean the MainWindow.xib(?) and this one had status bar but it didn't help removing it. any other suggestions. I get this behavior when starting a new project, and just adding a viewcontroller so I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: the 45.0f is just the height of the navigationbar , this is what i get when printing the frame though:
navigationbar frame: 
 x:0 
 y:0 
 width:0 
 height:1077149696
 (and it is exactly the same for the imageview and the self.view as well)